# How to integrate android maps application to my application in android?

Tags: android, google-maps

In my applicatiom , am ising google maps showing some events . But i want to navigation mechanism . SO i want to open in built google maps application . Can any one tell me how to integrate inbuilt application with my application .

Thanking you ,
Srinivas

Answer (score 0):

copy and pasted this from the DroidFu library

```
   public static Intent newMapsIntent(String address, String placeTitle) {
     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
     sb.append("geo:0,0?q=");

     String addressEncoded = Uri.encode(address);
     sb.append(addressEncoded);
     // pass text for the info window
     String titleEncoded = Uri.encode("(" + placeTitle + ")");
     sb.append(titleEncoded);
     // set locale; probably not required for the maps app?
     sb.append("&hl=" + Locale.getDefault().getLanguage());

     return new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(sb.toString()));
  }
```

Comment: I got it but is meaning of address here . I want send bunch of location to map. Can i send locations ? locate them in map?

Comment: I don't know that its possible but you could try comma separating the addresses or even try q=address1&q=address2 something like that.

Comment: I hav e lonitude and latitude . So i have to pass all lat and longs.